# How to send id from view to Controller CodeIgniter via form_open_multipart

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am trying to an send id from a view to controller in CodeIgniter.My requirement is to switch the functions based on button id.Here is my HTML code.

**View HTML**

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload_control/switch_load','id="bt_addImage"');?>
 <input id= "bt_addImage" type="submit" value="Add Image" /> <br>
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload_control/switch_load','id="bt_chooseImage"');?>
 <input type="submit" id="bt_chooseImage" value="Submit"/><br>
```

**`Upload_control.php` Code**

```
public function switch_load($id)
{
    if($id == "bt_addImage")
    {
        do_loadcategories();
    }
    else
    {
        do_upload();
    }
}
public function do_loadcategories()
{
    //code list categories
}
public function do_upload()
{
    //code to upload
}
```

is it corrrect?

or

have any other way to do this?

help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In View**

```
$hiddenFields = array('id' => 'bt_addImage'); # add Hidden parameters like this
echo form_open_multipart('upload_control/switch_load', '', $hiddenFields);
```

**In Controller**

```
public function switch_load()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    if($id == "bt_addImage")
    {
        do_loadcategories();
    }
    else
    {
        do_upload();
    }
}
```

view look like this

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/upload_control/switch_load">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="bt_addImage" /> # hidden filed.
```

[Codeigniter Form Helper](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form%20helper#available-functions)

Comment: I tried it ,but in my case i have two buttons ,when i add two form_open_multipart only one working at a time.

Comment: are you uplodaing file in form??

Comment: im unclear your commnt. **i add two form_open** whats this??

Comment: could you check html in my question,in html i am using two   "echo form_open_multipart"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99057/discussion-between-clifford-and-abdulla).

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
if($id == "bt_addImage")
```

Into

```
if($this->input->post('id') == "bt_addImage")
```